# Limit Azure Function to be called from just one domain

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Is there any way to limit an Azure function to just be allowed to be called from a particular domain? It is just in order to do not have an api exposed in public, I want that api to just be consumed from my webapp, deployed in a particular domain, let's say webappexample.org

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could implement with the `Access Restrictions` under the `Networking`, you could add access restriction rule to restrict  IPv4 ,  IPv6 or  Virtual Network.

Further more information you could refer to this official doc: [Azure App Service Access Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-functions%2Ftoc.json).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @George. As you can read in my question, I want to restrict by domain, not by ip or networking conditions. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I don't think function support the domain restrict, and you could get your azure web ip I don't think you have to use the domain to restrict it.